# Why do I get "syntax error, unexpected _end;" and "unexpected end-of-input"?

Tags: ruby

When I run my code I get really strange error messages:

```
/Users/Pan/Data/external/filter_url_1008.rb:35: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
/Users/Pan/Data/external/filter_url_1008.rb:45: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
filter_file.close
                 ^
```

I checked my Ruby code several times, but can't find out what's wrong.

```
#This script is for filterring any html files that doesn't abide the rule.
require "fileutils"

#path where html files will be read from
source_dir = "/20131008" 

#path where flittered html files will be copy to
dest_dir ="/20131008_filtered"

#file index to be filtered
filter_file = File.open("filtered_index.txt","r")

if !File.exist?(dest_dir) 
    FileUtils.mkdir_p("/dest_dir")
    print(dest_dir + " was created!\n") 
end

#filter rule
blacklist = ["facebook.com", "youtube.com", "twitter.com",
"linkedin.com", "bebo.com", "twitlonger.com", "bing.com", "ebay.com",
"ebayrt.com", "maps.google", "waze.com", "foursquare.com", "adf.ly", 
"twitpic.com","itunes.apple.com","craigslist.org","instagram.com", 
"google.com", "google.co.uk", "google.ie","bullhornreach", 
"pinterest.com", "feedsportal","tumblr.com"]

filter = filter_file.read

#Read from 20131008_filtered.txt and exclude urls that's in blacklist
filter.each_line do |line|
    $match_count = 0

    blacklist.each do |blacklist_atom|
        if !(line.downcase.include? "blacklist_atom")
            match_count += 1
        end
    end

    if (blacklist.length == match_count)
        filename_cp = line[line.index("20131008/") + 9..line.index(".html") - 1]
        filename = filename_cp.to_s + ".html"
        FileUtils.cp(source_dir + "/" + filename, dest_dir)
    end
end

filter_file.close
```

Comment: `ilename = filename_cp.to_s + ".html"`?

Comment: Sorry it's a type error, I've changed it. The problem is still the same, do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is to choose a bunch of html files that abide with the rules I set and copy them to a new folder.

Comment: @meagar `match_count ++` causes error...

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yes, I was `ruby -c test.rb` in the wrong directory; I need to stop leaving `test.rb`s laying around all over :|

Comment: Haven't solve my problem yet, but the posted question is already handled, the error message was because of the "match_count ++ "syntax I think.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the `++` operator in Ruby.
Use `match_count += 1` instead.

#### Edit

They're not "really strange error messages", it's just a message signaling a *syntax* error: the program hasn's even begun being interpreted, this is a pre-run check.

Comment: Yeah mine crashes too, but it's a non-existent directory error (`ENOENT`).

Comment: It's strange, I'll double check if anything else is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /20131008_filtered (Errno::EACCES)，I tried remove this piece of code of creating directory, still error. Need to check the whole code.

Comment: @user2641480 What you pasted is a permission error: you can't write to (aka create a directory in) `/System/...` without being root. Try to launch the program using `sudo` or, even better, try moving `/20131008_filtered` inside `~/` in order to avoid touching `/`.

Comment: Understood, trying to check the logic.

Comment: @user2641480 Since the answer actually *answers* your question, mark it as correct so that other people can see that.

Comment: Haven't fix the problem yet, sorry.

Comment: you have fixed the problem in the question, you now have an entirely different problem.

Comment: @user2641480 exactly like sevenseacat said.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `then` on the if statement lines?  It may be valid, but it sure isn't common usage.

Ruby also doesn't have a `++` operator.

Comment: Thanks, tried what you told me. Still not working, I'm wondering there may be something wrong with the directory path.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing several things wrong. This isn't an attempt to rewrite your code so it's error-free, it's to show how to write code in a more maintainable style and closer to the Ruby way:

```
require 'fileutils'

SOURCE_DIR = '/20131008' 
DEST_DIR ='/20131008_filtered'

BLACKLIST = %w[
  adf.ly
  bebo.com
  bing.com
  bullhornreach
  craigslist.org
  ebay.com
  ebayrt.com
  facebook.com
  feedsportal
  foursquare.com
  google.co.uk
  google.com
  google.ie
  instagram.com
  itunes.apple.com
  linkedin.com
  maps.google
  pinterest.com
  tumblr.com
  twitlonger.com
  twitpic.com
  twitter.com
  waze.com
  youtube.com
]

unless File.exist?(DEST_DIR) 
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(DEST_DIR)
  print(DEST_DIR + " was created!\n") 
end

File.foreach("filtered_index.txt") do |line|
  # $match_count = 0
  match_count = 0

  BLACKLIST.each do |blacklist_atom|
    match_count += 1 unless (line.downcase[blacklist_atom])
  end

  if (BLACKLIST.length == match_count)
    FileUtils.cp(
      File.join(
        SOURCE_DIR,
        File.basename(
          line,
          File.extname(line)
        ) + '.html'
      ),
      DEST_DIR
    )
  end
end
```

What's wrong:

- Use constants, and move them to the top of the file where they're easy to see/edit.
- Sort lists like the names of sites, so it's easier to edit/extend the list, and see whether you have an entry already.
- Don't open a file, do a bunch of stuff, then read it in its entirety into memory, do more stuff, split it, then iterate over the lines, then do a bunch of stuff, then close it. Instead, use more intelligent File methods, like `File.foreach` and use a block with it to open then close the file automatically. Reading a file completely into memory is a really bad habit because it isn't scalable at all; Imagine what will happen if the file is larger than the available memory to the program.
- You're not interpolating the variable into a string, plus you're adding an extra leading path delimiter:

  ```
  FileUtils.mkdir_p("/dest_dir")
  ```
- Don't use a "$global" variable in a block. That shows lack of understanding about variable scoping.
- The global variable `$match_count` is only initialized and not read.
- You can write a "not sub-string search" more succinctly:

  ```
  if !(line.downcase.include? "blacklist_atom")
  ```

  Using something like:

  ```
  unless line.downcase[blacklist_atom]
  ```
- Use built-in functionality:

  ```
  filename_cp = line[line.index("20131008/") + 9..line.index(".html") - 1]
  ```

  Instead, use `File.join(...)` because it knows what path separator your OS needs. Use `File.basename(...)` because it uses the same path separator to extract just the file.

Comment: Really, thanks for your help. I'm new to programming, will work harder in the future.